# Search for text within a file opened in eclipse that is not part of a project.

Tags: eclipse

This really should be incredibly simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

This involves searching for a text string in a random file opened in eclipse using the file|Open file.. option and then opening a file (naturally) from my file system.  In this case, the file is a massive .css file that is completely unrelated to any project.

I click on the search tool, or press ctrl-H and up pops the search window.  It really doesn't matter which tab I select because none of them return known results.  If I select 'file search', then uncheck 'case-sensitive', then select file pattern *.*, or even *.css, then select workspace (only option available) and then search, I get back zero results, when in fact, I really should get back dozens.. (I'm searching for 'padding'.)

Search works fine for me when I'm in a project, but what is the catch if you just want to search a random file?  The complexity here is a little amusing. Really a right click option to 'search this file' would be awesome and would really help immensely when trying to search for an isolated div in a massive .css file.

Comment: And yes, I know, the outline makes finding a div simple.. I was being hypothetical.. lets assume I need to find a reference to a font family..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Ctrl-F to search within an open file/window.
(I'm using STS Eclipse)

Comment: Awesome.. That's the ticket.  I searched all over the eclipse wiki and support pages.. I guess, "search open file for text" was the incorrect approach. I saw that in the Edit tab but assumed it was a link to the search window that had failed me before.